# VBA Macro Subtract Weekdays from Two Date Column

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I'm trying to minus weekdays between two days from two columns using Networkdays.Intl.

But the error shows

> Object-required.

How I need to solve this? I'm actually unsure the way I'm using Networkdays.Intl is correct or not.

Here is my code :

```
Private Sub MinusWeekDays()
    Dim InitialRow As Long
    Dim EndRow As Long
    Dim lrow As Long

    Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
    Set CurrentSheet = Excel.ActiveSheet

    InitialRow = CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    EndRow = CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Rows(CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count).Row

    For lrow = EndRow To InitialRow Step -1
        CurrentSheet.Cells(lrow, "AH").Value = NetworkDays.Intl((CurrentSheet.Cells(lrow, "W").Value), (CurrentSheet.Cells(lrow, "V").Value), (CurrentSheet.Cells(lrow, "AG").Value))
    Next lrow
End Sub
```

I'm also tried to replace CurrentSheet.Cells(lrow, "AG").Value) directly with '11' by doing Dim intdays As Integer, intdays = 11 coz to avoid needs for creating a column with value 11 only but seems failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have missed the [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx) from the call to [NETWORKDAYS.INTL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-INTL-function-A9B26239-4F20-46A1-9AB8-4E925BFD5E28). I've moved the repetitive call to the worksheet into a surrounding [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx).

```
WITH CurrentSheet
    For lrow = EndRow To InitialRow Step -1
        .Cells(lrow, "AH").Value = WORKSHEETFUNCTION.NetworkDays_Intl(.Cells(lrow, "W"), .Cells(lrow, "V"), 11)
    Next lrow
END WITH
```

Are the types of weekends really that different for each line that you cannot just put a number in the third parameter instead of `.Cells(lrow, "AG")`? Check the official documentation for the [NETWORKDAYS.INTL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-INTL-function-A9B26239-4F20-46A1-9AB8-4E925BFD5E28) to make sure you are providing the correct parameters.

Comment: It shows error "Argument not optional". How to slove this?

Comment: My apologies. It should have been `NetworkDays_Intl` as a VBA call, not `NetworkDays.Intl`.